# What plugin do I need to install for Firefox to show the content of these websites?

Tags: firefox, java

I am trying on some VoIP quality test websites Firefox, but because of lack of some plugins, I can't do the test. See the screenshots below. 
What plugins do I need?

The second screenshot says "This requires a web browser with Java 1.5 (Version 5.0) or greater." I think my installed Java is ok, because the version of Java on my Ubuntu 14.04 is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)
```

The following's URL is http://myspeed.visualware.com/test.php?testtype=-1&codebase=98.159.220.6&location=USA:%20Rochester,%20New%20York&cm=no&map=namerica&lines=1&pps=50&bpp=60&codec=G.726%20%2824%20Kbps%29&provtext=Finger%20Lakes%20Technologies%20Group&provlink=http://www.fltg.com&ver=97g

[image]

The following's URL is https://info.onsip.com/thank-you/voip-test?submissionGuid=dbca4c0e-4b11-47da-9d23-82a2d73d0930

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `icedtea-7-plugin` this is not installed by default

Run this command to install the plugin

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin
```

then you should be able to run Java on the website. refresh the page to apply changes

Now it will block Java from running in the web page which is good. all you need to do to enable Java on that page is click on the `Active icedtea-web`. 
[image]

And it works Java my warn you multiple times saying its unsafe but if you trust the web site go head.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have installed Oracle's JDK, why doesn't it work for Firefox and the websites?

Comment: @Tim its works in Firefox. did you install  `icedtea-7-plugin`.

Comment: no I didn't. but I installed Oracle's JDK, which version was shown in my post. But Firefox seems not able to use it. Now I just installed icedtea-7-plugin, and Firefox can use it, so I wonder why having Oracle's JDK  only does not work.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim  ... I am using ubuntu 14.04 as well with the following Java-version

java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)

The applets ran without any issues.

The iced-tea-7-plugin i believe is what made the difference.

Hope that helps